# Use YAML anchors for both scalars and lists

Tags: yaml

I want to convert YAML scalars to a list using aliases (I hope that's the correct terminology).

```yaml
variables:
  - &USERNAME secret_username
  - &TOKEN secret_token

restore:
  secrets:                   # this expects a list
    - *USERNAME
    - *TOKEN

push:
  password:
    from_secret: *TOKEN      # this expects a scalar
```

Without the `restore` block, the yaml parses and works (in my CI tool).

With the `restore:` block, I get a parser error and failure:

> failed to parse pipeline: yaml: unknown anchor 'USERNAME' referenced

(It fails for `*USERNAME` only because it's first; if I reversed the order then it would log an error for `*TOKEN`.)

I don't know how to define those variables once and use them in both the `restore` and `push` blocks. *Is my syntax correct?*

Comment: this yaml is valid and your parser have problem with achnors you can check how to expand yaml and merges them using python : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968474/tool-to-automatically-expand-yaml-merges

Comment: @Lapwood Thank you. I was wondering whether my yaml is incorrect, or the tool reading it is incorrect. That yaml seems to parse correctly in other tools. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: also try to remove the comments "# this expects a scalar" and " # this expects a list" or use only one space for comments like this "from_secret: *TOKEN # this expects a scalar"
 and try to parse it again because some parser have issue with too many spaces if the parser issue then change it

Comment: @Lapwood I confirmed with the ci tool authors that it is not parsing properly, so you were right. That syntax should be correct. Thanks for your advice and reviewing my code!

Comment: happy to help i write a quick answer to marke the thread solved

Answer (score 1):

your yaml is valid and your parser seem to have issues with anchors or comments try to use another yaml parser should solve your problem